# How to show that $\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}\,dt>xe^{-x^2} \quad \forall x>0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is there any particular inequality involving $e^{x^2}$ that I need to use here? In any case, I couldn't solve it.

Comment: The, decreasing,  integrand has its minimum value at $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. One may differentiate
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}\,dt-xe^{-x^2} 
$$ obtaining
$$
f'(x)=2x^2e^{-x^2}>0,\quad x>0,
$$ then one may use $f(0)=0$.

Comment: So $f$ is strictly increasing $\forall x>0$, implying $f(x)>0$?

Comment: Exactly @StubbornAtom

Answer (score 6):

$$\int_{0}^{x}e^{x^2-t^2}\,dt \stackrel{t=xs}{=} x\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2(1-s^2)}\,ds > x\int_{0}^{1}1\,ds = x.$$

Comment: What is the basis for the inequality?

Comment: @StubbornAtom: simple: if $u>0$, $e^u>1$.

Answer (score 4):

$e^{-t^2}$ is strictly decreasing for positive $t$. So the function you're integrating is always at least $e^{-x^2}$ for $t$ between $0$ and $x$. So $\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt > \int_0^xe^{-x^2}dt = xe^{-x^2} - 0e^{-x^2} = xe^{-x^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

The rectangle $[0,x]\times[0,e^{-x^2}]$ lies entirely below the graph of $e^{-x^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Set $e^{-t^2}=u$ and $dt=dv$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt=xe^{-x^2}+2\int_{0}^{x}t^2e^{-t^2}dt$$
since $x>0$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt> xe^{-x^2}$$